# DNN Error when loading a specific skin (GeneralContentPage)

Tags: dotnetnuke, skins

I get this error when I load a page that uses a specific skin (GeneralContentPage). I have deleted the ascx page and parsed the skins again but still have the same error. Would appreciate any input!

An error has occurred.
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement) at DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.CreateValidID(String inputValue) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.Styles.AddStyleSheet() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnn\5.1.0\Mr Video\Admin\Skins\Styles.ascx.vb:line 107 at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.Styles.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnn\5.1.0\Mr Video\Admin\Skins\Styles.ascx.vb:line 88 at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If skin is set at portal level. go to site settings and change the skin to default (minimal extropy)

If skin is ste at tab level, you have to go to Host > Sql and reset the skin src of the tab.